# Print string to console log in human friendly syntax

Tags: python-3.x, string, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below strings from list object:

```
'items.find({"repo": "lld-test-helm", "path": "customer-customer", "name": "customer-customer-0.29.4.tgz", "type": "file"})'

'items.find({"repo": "lld-test-docker", "path": "docker.io/ubuntu/18.05", "type": "file"})'
```

can you please suggest how to manipulate and print it (using python 3) in human-friendly syntax to pipeline console? for example:

```
repository: lld-test-helm
chart: customer-customer
version: 0.29.4

repository name: lld-test-dokcer
image: docker.io/ubuntu
tag: 18.05
```

Comment: you could write a function to parse each string individually and then print the relevant parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use builtin eval() method to change your string to actual dict.
Of course you need to get rid of *items.find(* part and the right bracket *)*

If string always start with *items.find(*, you can do it that way:

```
a = 'items.find({"repo": "lld-test-docker", "path": "docker.io/ubuntu/18.05", "type": "file"})'
a = a[11:-1]
```

or just use replace:

```
a = a.replace('items.find(', '')[:-1]
```

then use, as mentioned before, eval():

```
a = eval(a)
```

Now you can iterate thru an dict:

```
for key in a:
    print(key, ' : ', a[key])
```

Example how to parse output to match one from your question:

```
b = {"repo": "lld-test-docker", "path": "docker.io/ubuntu/18.05", "type": "file"}
for item in b:
if item == "repo":
    print('repository : ', b[item])
if item == "path":
    if "ubuntu" in b[item]:
        separator = len('ubuntu')+b[item].find('ubuntu')
        print('image : ', b[item][:separator])
        print('tag : ', b[item][separator+1:])
```

Comment: Obviously this is simpler output, than you presented in question, but from what i provided, implementing it should be easy

Comment: Mandatory warning to use eval() wit caution, especially if the data you are inserting is from user input or unknown source, since it is used to execute string as code

Comment: Tnx man. can you suggest how to modify your code to print the way I suggested?

Comment: Tnx, but how can I ask instead of "ubuntu" in, the value between the two slashes?

Comment: @arielma Just add other elif statements with similar structure

Comment: no, but I want always to grab the value between the two slashes, instead of using the hardcoded word

Comment: @arielma In that case you can use split('/') method for string.